# JavaScript sample code loading blank page in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I can't make this sample code to load properly in Google Chrome; it loads a blank page.  What seems to be wrong with the code?

Code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN” “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”> 

<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myString = “56.02 degrees centigrade”; 
            var myInt;
            var myFloat;

            document.write(“\“” + myString + “\“ is “ + parseInt(myString) + 
            “ as an integer” + “<BR>”);

            myInt = parseInt(myString);
            document.write(“\“” + myString + “\“ when converted to an integer equals “ +
            myInt + “<BR>”);

            myFloat = parseFloat(myString); document.write(“\“” + myString +
            “\“ when converted to a floating point number equals “ + myFloat);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's probably those weird quotes you are using. Try using an actual `"` or `'` character.

Comment: Are you coding in Word?

Comment: Just TextPad = Notepad in Windows ;-) Salamat po! (Many thanks guys!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dave was absolutely right, it was the quotes. This version, with fixed quotes, loads in my Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myString = "56.02 degrees centigrade"; 
var myInt;
var myFloat;

document.write("\"" + myString + "\" is " + parseInt(myString) + 
" as an integer" + "<BR>");

myInt = parseInt(myString);
document.write("\"" + myString + "\" when converted to an integer equals " +
myInt + "<BR>");

myFloat = parseFloat(myString); document.write("\"" + myString +
"\" when converted to a floating point number equals " + myFloat);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I'm seeing:
[image]

Comment: No problem @Ron! Don't forget to select it as the answer if you found it most useful.